# Ubuntu 12.04 to 16 upgrade - Mysql dangers?

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, mysql

I'm on 12.04 and MySQL 5.5, running `do-release-upgrade` will upgrade it to 14 and then again running it will upgrade it 16. During this time I think MySQL upgrades to 5.6 (while on 14) and then to 5.7. I fear that MySQL will break in someway?

There's a quite a few posts about it. I'll take a full backup and configs. But what should I be aware of before upgrading a DB server OS? Few days ago I read that tables types are different in MySQL 5.7, couldn't find the link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I experienced. I had to clone a VM and try it. It is **dangerous** if you proceed upgrading OS before upgrading MySQL.

Reasons: It can break your upgrade, data corruptions, it might get **stuck** when its setting up apparmor related stuff (kinda waiting for input but you don't see any input request and it won't proceed further).

Best approach is (backup first) upgrade MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6 then run `mysql-upgrade` command to fix tables and then update MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 (again run `mysql_upgrade` command to fix tables).

If all goes well and MySQL can re-start, take a fresh all database backup, then you can proceed with Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04 upgrade. This will skip the part of MySQL packages and everything will be fine. Once the upgrade is finished, you might need to edit apparmor OR disable apparmor for MySQL to start, just check the mysql logs.